# Creating a collapsible side bar - Alternative to navigation drawer?

Tags: android, sidebar

I'm trying to create a collapsible side bar with buttons. Is there another alternative to NavigationDrawer, or is that the best choice for this design? I've also noticed Navigation Drawer doesn't have a thumbnail button that you can click to expand it.

What I'm trying to create:

[image]

Comment: You have to create your own custom views for this. [Basics on Custom Components](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components)

Comment: You can make your own view and display it as custom size fragment in your activity. you can use animation to show or hide this fragment.